# R, error message when running dredge on model with interaction term

Tags: r

I am running the following model.

```
mod<-lme(LagTime~a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+h*i,weights=varConstPower(form=~fitted(.)),random=~1|ID,data=DIVE, method="ML")
```

The model runs fine with and without the interaction term, my issue arises when I try to dredge (MuMIN). I get the following error message when the interaction term is included.

```
Error in expr.split(ret, ":", prepare = function(x) gsub("((?<=:):|:(?=:))",  : 
  4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3
```

Apologies if this is a basic question, I am a relative novice with modelling.
I am just wondering if anyone has come across this before, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure this will fix it, but you only need `h*i` to include main effects and interaction effects. If you want to keep them all explicitly, use `h+i+h:i`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but unfortunately I am getting the same error message either way.